# bad major version , trying to get keycloak to run in java 5

Tags: java, maven, keycloak

I'm generating a jar file with maven using compiler.target 1.5. Logically thinking the output jar should be compatible with java 1.5.  However when i manually put the jar file inside my ear, during runtime i get the bad major version offset=6. I am indeed running java 5, with no possibility to upgrade. Any ideas what I can do? See my partial maven pom below. Thanks!

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source> 
    <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target> 
</properties> 
<dependencies> 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId> 
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId> 
        <version>2.5.1.Final</version>
```

Comment: It is highly likely that you compiled code with JDK 1.6 but running it with Java 5. Can you check installed Java version?

Comment: my installed java version that maven is using is java 8. You should be able to compile with backwards compatibility right?

Comment: You should be able to compile with different version but it seems like mismatch of version. Could be either jar file compiled with different version than running EAR?

Comment: Maven website answers my question partially. I think I am out of luck:
Note: Merely setting the target option does not guarantee that your code actually runs on a JRE with the specified version. The pitfall is unintended usage of APIs that only exist in later JREs which would make your code fail at runtime with a linkage error.